# localhost added to href (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I built a menu using `Link` component in NextJs using `href=#contact`. Unfortunately, when I querySelect this `a` element, the`href` became `http://localhost:3000/#contact'` and I can't scroll into that. What is happening and how to get only `#contact` as `href`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an `a` tag in the first. `next/link` doesn't work well with internal links.

Comment: the same error :(